# what are the steps tomcat follows to open homepage(Ex:Index.jsp) in browser when we click on "Run on Server" option in Ecclips

Tags: java, tomcat

Actually i heard that some build.XML reading takes place,really i don't no
exactly,so any one tell what are the steps tomcat follows to open 
homepage(Ex:Index.jsp) 
in browser when we click on "Run on Server" option in Eclipse.

Comment: Not able to understand exactly what is required

Comment: Ok let me put in this way sir,what are the steps tomcat follows to open homepage(Ex:Index.jsp) in browser when we click on "Run on Server" option in Ecclips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click "Run on server", Eclipse deploys the application in Tomcat, opens a new browser window to the URL of the JSP in the deployed webapp.

So an HTTP request is sent to Tomcat by the browser. Since the URL of the HTTP request points to a .jsp file, Tomcat loads the corresponding JSP file in the webapp, transforms it into a Java source file containing a class which extends HttpServlet, then invokes the Java compiler to compile this Java source file into a class file.

Then the class file is loaded by the Tomcat classloader associated with the webapp, an instance of the JSP servlet is constructed and initialized, and its service method is called.

The service method generates HTML and writes it to the servlet's response writer, which is in fact a writer wrapping the socket output stream which sends the bytes to the browser.

The browser interprets the HTML and generates text and graphics to be shown in the browser window.

Of course, if a second request is sent to the same JSP, Tomcat reuses the servlet instance it has created to serve the first request, and just reinvokes the service method of this servlet. That's why the first request is generally slow, and the subsequent ones are blazingly fast.